# Are there any dangers/concerns for downgrading python 3.8 to 3.7 (VM)

Tags: python, ubuntu

I've recently installed an Ubuntu VM, and it came with python 3.8. However this is version of python is incompatible with a lot of programs I want to use, so I was looking at downgrading it. But looking at different posts, it seems basic linux programs are dependent on the built in python, and removing/modifying it could break those programs. Thus:

1. Should I/can I keep 3.8 and just download 3.7 as well (and just use 3.7 for all my uses)
2. Can I delete 3.8 and reinstall 3.7 (will I need to reconfigure all the programs with it though? Since they will break if I delete 3.8)

Comment: In general, and specifically in your situation, I recommend installing [pyenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/) which will let you install several versions of python in your local home folder completely independently of system python, easily switch between them, and even set up directory-specific versions. This way you can use 3.7 for your work and leave the system python alone. (For your other question—yes you can uninstall 3.8 and install 3.7 and all other programs depending on Python will be able to find the new version but I see that as a needless headache when we have pyenv.)

Comment: wouldn't it be even more of a headache to constantly have to specify python3.7 everytime I want to install/use/run something? I already have to do python3 because this came built in with both python2 and python3

Comment: you don't have to downgrade but install second version and you will have commands `python3.7` and `python3.8` and `pip3.7` and `pip3.8`. And it is not headache. If you remove 3.8 then maybe some functions in system may crash. BTW: in Linux you can use shebang (`#!`) in first line of script with `python3.7 or `python3.8` and set it executable `chmod +x script.py` and then you can run it as any other program using only script.py` and it will use first line with shebang to run it.

Comment: One final question, I've installed python3.7 using pyenv, however how do I incorporate this into my main files? Do I have to manually move it to my usr/bin/python file? Currently its in pyenv file, and when I type python3.7 in the terminal, it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally I would not change version of python, that a linux distribution is delivered with.

I personally use pyenv to compile and download other than the system's python versions and virtualenv to create one virtualenv per project.
Then you can use direnv or autoenv to automatically activate them if you cd in a projects directory.

Relevant links:

- https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv
- https://pypi.org/project/virtualenv/
- https://github.com/direnv/direnv

To install pyenv something like:

```
git clone https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv.git ~/.pyenv
echo 'export PYENV_ROOT="$HOME/.pyenv"' >> ~/.bashrc
echo 'export PATH="$PYENV_ROOT/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bashrc
echo -e 'if command -v pyenv 1>/dev/null 2>&1; then\n  eval "$(pyenv init -)"\nfi' >> ~/.bashrc
exec "$SHELL"
```

To download / install python3.7

```
pyenv install
3.7.7
```

To install virtualenv for this python version

```
~/.pyenv/versions/3.7.7/bin/python -m pip install -U pip virtualenv
```

To create a virtualenv for a projet

```
venv_path="~/venv/pjt1"  # set the value where your project's venv should be stored
~/.pyenv/versions/3.7.7/bin/python -m virtualenv -p ~/.pyenv/versions/3.7.7/bin/python "$venv_path"
```

```
source $venv_path/bin/activate
```